# Dynamically declare variables/structure in C

Tags: c

For example, I have a file, which says

```
char,5
int,6
```

Reading the above file, is it possible to declare 2 variable array in the code? So in future
if i add a new line it will automatically declare?

Comment: What do the words "it will automatically declare" mean? This question is lacking many important details. How would you go on to *use* these data types?

Comment: As it stands, the following would work: Open the file in an editor, open your source code file, and type `struct { char a[5]; int b[6]; };` To automate, hire an intern. Are you talking about a code generator?

Comment: would this be achievable in c++11 with lvalue references ?

Answer (score 2):

No, not in C.
You will need to write a script which reads this file and writes the c program.
In short, what you need is a **C Source Code Generator**.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just code exactly what you want. You can start with a structure that can hold either a character or an integer (with some boolean or integer to indicate which). Then you can allocate an array of them of any size.

When you read the first line, create an array of 5 such structures. Set their type variable to "char".

When you read the second lien, increase the size by 6. Set those six new ones to be integers.

And so on.

You can use an `enum` to track the type of each entry in the array. You can use a `struct` to hold the integer value, character value, (or just re-use the integer value) and  type. You can make helper functions like `isInteger`, `setIntegerValue`, `getCharacterValue`, and so on.

Comment: Even if doing above for some practical reason that i can't comprehend, wouldn't using a union and plainly using the corresponding field be better?

Comment: @fayyazkl: You could, but I don't think it would be any better. Perhaps if you expect a number of large types to be added later, it might save some memory. But that hardly seems relevant here.